# Can I linearize a System of SDE without losing the constant terms?

Tags: linearization

I have the following system:

$dx/dt = con_1 + a_1k_1y - k_1x$

$dy/dt = con_2 + b_1k_2x + b_2k_2x^2- k_2y$

that I want to linearize.

However, I'm not able to do it properly, because my aim is to linearize the system, estimate the parameters (of the linearized system) and then use the result as a starting point for a new estimation carried out on the non-linear system (the original one).

But when I linearize, I will lose the terms $con_1$ and $con_2$.

Any help?

Thank you very much in advance!